# Is it safe to upgrade to Xcode 7.1 while writing a project using Xcode 7 and Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I am on my first project and using `Xcode 7` with `Swift 2`. I would like to **upgrade** to Xcode 7.1 to be able run the application on my iPhone `without a paid developer account`. Since Xcode 7.1 introduces Swift 2.1, I am not sure if I should upgrade.

Is it safe to upgrade to Xcode 7.1?

Comment: You can install both XCode versions and test by yourself.

Comment: Yes it is safe and good.

Comment: Apple has not changed plan for xcode 7.1 update.You can test your app without developer account in xcode 7.1 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you work alone for the project,it is safe to update.
- If you work in a team to develop a project together,and you are using version control tools such as **GIT**,better to keep XCode version same.So,either all the team update,either none

Answer (score 1):

There are Lot of Improvements in Xcode 7.1 
apart from once mentioned my apple

I saw a good stability while accecing objects from other frameworks. 
The big advantage comes when you dont need to have Developer program  to test apps on device. Go for it. And if its a team project a good update is always welcome.